# Probability of kitchen toaster breaking

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, mechanical-failure, data, failure-analysis

does anyone have any data on the probability of a kitchen toaster breaking such as mechanical or electrical faults?

For a school project- teacher put me in charge to find this

Comment: Right now the problem is to broad to answer.  Try breaking the problem down into the major systems, to major component, and sub-components.  Then look for reliability metrics like MTBF, MTTF, B10 for those sub-components.  You can really go deep on this project by doing a reliability block diagram.

Comment: contact a toaster manufacturer

Comment: Remember that the process of finding the information is how you learn, not the accuracy of the answer. You should first establish what "breaking" means. There are many ways it could break and components which would cause that; write those down, then ask specific questions about those things. The other method is to survey friends and family of how long they have had a toaster and if it ever broke; then calculate the statistics based on that sample.

Comment: Do cheaper ones fail first? What about design life?

Comment: Were you asked to find data or to estimate?

Comment: Hi, I’m still in school by the way, this is just for something to show the kids for ‘high school open day’. I could just make it up, but I wanted to try and do this properly.      Then, my maths teacher said he’ll show me how to work out probability of certain bits after to present

Comment: Pretty much universally, pop up toasters fail because the nickel chromium heating elements fail. Years ago heating elements were robust wound wires and lasted indefinitely. Now, heating elements are very thin ribbons that wear out. Wirecutter has a review of toasters where they cover exactly this.